# How to use Dockerfile with different name in OCP Git source build

Tags: openshift

I am trying to create a [Git source](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/builds/creating-build-inputs.html#source-code_creating-build-inputs) build of this Dockerfile: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker/blob/master/ga/latest/full/Dockerfile.ubi.ibmjava8

I have the following configuration in my BuildConfig:

```yaml
source:
  git: 
    uri: "https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker"
    ref: "master"
  contextDir: "ga/latest/full"
```

However, the above assumes the use of the `Dockerfile` filename while I want to use `Dockerfile.ubi.ibmjava8` as in `docker build -f Dockerfile.ubi.ibmjava8 .`.

How can I use Dockerfile.ubi.ibmjava8 instead of Dockerfile in OpenShift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Yes. You will not be able to use a Dockerfile with a different name than `Dockerfile`

On [Build Strategy Options](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.htm) on section [Dockerfile Path](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#dockerfile-path) you will find the constrains of OCP regarding the Docker Strategy:

> By default, Docker builds use a Dockerfile (named Dockerfile) located
>   at the root of the context specified in the
>   BuildConfig.spec.source.contextDir field.
>
> The dockerfilePath field allows the build to use a different path to
>   locate your Dockerfile, relative to the
>   BuildConfig.spec.source.contextDir field. It can be simply a different
>   file name other than the default Dockerfile (for example,
>   MyDockerfile), or a path to a Dockerfile in a subdirectory (for
>   example, dockerfiles/app1/Dockerfile).

And they also use an expample:

```
strategy:
  dockerStrategy:
    dockerfilePath: dockerfiles/app1/Dockerfile
```

Comment: is it possible to specify this option using the CLI tool oc? 'oc new-build --dockerpath=<my-path>'

Answer (score 1):

well, while it's not possible to directly supply `dockerfilePath` when using the `oc new-build` command as an option, it is possible to create a new build and then edit it right away with 'oc patch'. so

```
$ oc new-build ...
$ oc patch bc/my-build-config --type=json -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/strategy/dockerStrategy/dockerfilePath", "value": "my-new-dockerfile"}]'
```

works like charm